# Perl - Removing multiple lines from file with multiple regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm (obviously) new to Perl and am trying to create a simple script to clean up a large file on about 4.5 million records on a weekly basis.  I want to completely remove the lines that match one of three patterns.  The file looks like this:

```
D0832
G2565
ZDS97
FHM2547
JDH1464
R2918
4918K
AG01023
AG02997
```

My script below works, but I get a blank line where a deletion occurs (substitution) rather than removing the line completely.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open( FH, "serial.txt" ) || die "Couldn't open file...\n";

while ( <FH> ) {
   $data .= $_;
}

$data =~ s/[A][F|G][(0-9)]{5}//g;
$data =~ s/[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]//g;
$data =~ s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]//g;

print $data;
close( FH );
```

My question is - with 4.5 million records, running this at least once a week, is this an efficient/fast way to accomplish what I want to do, or is there a more efficient way to do it?  In addition, how can I remove the lines rather than substituting a blank line?

Thanks all.    Stephen

Comment: About how to delete the lines - include `\n` at the end of your find regexes. About is it fast enough - it would definitely pass in a week timeframe, but you have to test and see if it satisfactory yourself :)

Comment: `[(0-9)]` also matches `(` and `)`. Similarly, `[F|G]` also matches `|`.

Comment: Have you considered not using perl at all for this problem.  `grep -v 'regexp'` will do the work better I think.  See option `-v` in manual page of **grep(1)** utility.  Grep is good on filtering lines of text.  It has been developed with that target in mind.  And is at least ten years older than perl.

Answer (score 3):

@ndn's comment is correct. However, personally, rather than reading in the whole file, I'd process it line by line (I took the liberty to tidy up your regexes, too):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_ = '' if /^A[FG]\d{5}$/ || /^[A-Z]\d{4}$/ || /^\d{4}[A-Z]$/;
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
print unless /^A[FG]\d{5}$/ || /^[A-Z]\d{4}$/ || /^\d{4}[A-Z]$/;
```

(In both cases, specify your input file on the command line. Read up the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) manual page on how the `-p` and `-n` options work.)

Comment: All of these suggestions are great!  Major progress, thank you.  Only one issue with my regex - this is filtering FHM2547 and JDH1464 which I want to keep.  I only want to delete lines that match exactly rather than a portion.  Would I use ^ and $?

Comment: @StephenDundas Yep, anchor all the regexes with `^` and `$`. I'll edit my answer to incorporate.

Answer (score 3):

At first pass, I'd make a list of pre-compiled patterns to test against each line. The problem is likely to change and I want to add and delete patterns without disturbing the meat of the code:

```
my @patterns = ( 
    qr/\A [A] [FG]  [0-9]{5} \Z/x,
    qr/\A [A-Z]     [0-9]{4} \Z/x,
    qr/\A [0-9]{4}  [A-Z]    \Z/x,
    );

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if grep { $line =~ $_ } @patterns;

    print $line;
    }

__END__
D0832
G2565
ZDS97
FHM2547
JDH1464
R2918
4918K
AG01023
AG02997
```

The big improvement isn't the patterns though. It's checking things one line at a time and printing the lines I want to keep. I don't have the entire file in memory at the same time; it's only a line at a time.

There's a problem with this though. It works, but it checks every pattern every time. That might not mean much if very few lines will ever match or there are only a few patterns. If you think it might matter, using `first` from [List::Util](http://www.metacpan.org/module/List::Util) instead of `grep` can help since it only needs to find one match and stops when it finds it:

```
use List::Util qw(first);

my @patterns = ( 
    qr/\A [A] [FG]  [0-9]{5} \Z/x,
    qr/\A [A-Z]     [0-9]{4} \Z/x,
    qr/\A [0-9]{4}  [A-Z]    \Z/x,
    );

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if first { $line =~ $_ } @patterns;

    print $line;
    }

__END__
D0832
G2565
ZDS97
FHM2547
JDH1464
R2918
4918K
AG01023
AG02997
```

Or, I might make one giant pattern. [Regexp::Assemble](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Assemble) can put them together (but so can you if you watch out for the alternation precedence):

```
use v5.10;

use Regexp::Assemble;

my @patterns = ( 
    '[A][FG][0-9]{5}',
    '[A-Z][0-9]{4}',
    '[0-9]{4}[A-Z]',
    );

my $grand_pattern = do {
    my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
    $ra->add( $_ ) for @patterns;
    my $re = $ra->re;
    qr/ \A (?: $re ) \Z /x;
    };

say "Grand regex is $grand_pattern";

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next if $line =~ $grand_pattern;

    print $line;
    }

__END__
D0832
G2565
ZDS97
FHM2547
JDH1464
R2918
4918K
AG01023
AG02997
```

The next step would be to take the patterns from the command line or a configuration file, but that's not so hard. The program shouldn't know the patterns at all. You'll have a much easier time changing the patterns if you don't have to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for multiple regex patterns. This will do what you need

```perl
perl -ne'print unless /^(?:[A][FG]\d{5}|[A-Z]\d{4}|\d{4}[A-Z])$/' serial.txt
```

#### output

```
ZDS97
FHM2547
JDH1464
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $data =~ s/[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][\s\r\n]*//g;
 $data =~ s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][\s\r\n]*//g;
```

From the question:

> "how can I remove the lines rather than substituting a blank line?"

End of the each regex which we can have a linebreak/returns. And then regex will replacing the empty line. Hence I have added the [\s\r\n]* syntax and it will not replace the empty line.

Comment: Please add explanation